# rindex in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string

I think, there is no builtin function rindex (like in perl) to get the position of the last occurrence of a character in a string.

I tried in a naive way like this

```
func rindex (_ s:String, _ needle:Character) -> Int?
{  var  pos = s.characters.count

   for char in s.characters.reversed()
   { 
     if (char == needle)
     { return pos;
     }
     pos -= 1
   }
   return nil
}
```

Is  there a more elegant way for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend making this an extension of `String` (or even `String.CharacterView`) rather than a free-floating function. Also, given that strings are indexed by [`String.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string.characterview.index) rather than `Int`, I would advise returning that instead.

You could then implement it like so:

```
extension String {
    func lastIndex(of character: Character) -> Index? {
        return characters.indices.reversed().first(where: {self[$0] == character})
    }
}
```

- [`indices`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641719-indices) gives you the indices of the string's characters.
- [`reversed()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/bidirectionalcollection/1782128-reversed) gives you a reversed view onto these indices.
- [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1849238-first) iterates through the these reversed indices until it finds the index where the element at that index is the character you're looking for.

You can then use it like so:

```
let string = "foobarbaz"

if let index = string.lastIndex(of: "a") {
    print(index) // Index(_base: Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 7), _countUTF16: 1)
    print(string[index]) // "a"
}
```