# How should i get the last index of an object that passes a test as an Int?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to get the index of the last object in my array of messages which passes a test.

Here's what I'm doing so far. I have an array of message `Dictionary` objects: `[[String:Any]]`

I'm getting the index of the last object:

```
let lastStatusUpdateIndex = messages.reversed().index { message in
    guard let type = message["type"] as? String else { return false }
    guard type == "Status Change" else { return false }
    return true
}
```

To work get the integer of the index, I was expecting to do either

`let position = messages.startIndex.distance(to: lastStatusUpdateIndex)`

or

`let position = messages.distance(from: messages.startIndex, to: lastStatusUpdateIndex)`

But these methods take an Int or two Ints (respectively)

What's the correct way to do this? (I understand that the index would be coming from the end of the array rather than the start, but I can deal with that)

I'm using Swift 3.1.

Many thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but this looks like a completely inappropriate data structure – almost certainly you should have an array of `Message` structs, with an `enum` to represent the type of message (don't use stringly typed code). Then the test is as simple as `message.type != .statusChanged`.

Comment: messages.reversed.index { ... } is returning a `ReversedRandomAccessIndex<[[String : Any]]>?`

Comment: Yup, I was mistaken into thinking you were calling the overload of `reversed()` that returned an array – my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index can only be used with the collection that it belongs to.
In your case, `lastStatusUpdateIndex` (which is a `ReversedRandomAccessIndex`) can only be used with the collection
returned by `messages.reversed()` (which is a `ReversedRandomAccessCollection`).

So you can compute the distance of `lastStatusUpdateIndex` to
the `startIndex` of the reverse collection, and that is an `Int`:

```
let messages = Array(0...10) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

let revMessages = messages.reversed() // a ReversedRandomAccessCollection
if let lastStatusUpdateIndex = (revMessages.index { message in
    message % 3 == 0 } ) {

    let pos = revMessages.distance(from: revMessages.startIndex,
                                   to: lastStatusUpdateIndex)
    print(pos) // 1
}
```

Alternatively, use that `ReversedRandomAccessIndex`
has a `base` property which is the position *after*
its corresponding position in the underlying collection. (This was wrongly 
documented in Swift 3, but has been fixed for Swift 4,
compare [SR-3650 - Transforming an index from a reversed() array is off by one](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3650).)

In your case the underlying collection is an `Array`, so that
`lastStatusUpdateIndex.base` is an `Int`:

```
if let lastStatusUpdateIndex = (messages.reversed().index { message in
    message % 3 == 0 } ) {

    let pos = lastStatusUpdateIndex.base -  1
    print(pos) // 9
}
```

Comment: Although note that the `base` index will always be the index *after* the base index you actually want (this is because the reversed view's indices start at `endIndex`). Another alternative is to use `.indices.reversed().first(where: {...})`, which avoids that problem ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41558471/2976878)).

Comment: @Hamish: You are right, thanks! With your approach you would need a subscript operation in the closure, so here it is perhaps easier to subtract one from the result.

Comment: True, I would agree that just adjusting the result is easier in this case :) Although for collections with non-integer indices, it's usually easier to reverse the base indices (you can see the fun I had [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41558778/revisions) of my answer there :P)

Comment: @martin Thanks for your solution, but I've gone with Hamish's `indices` example, as these seems to bypass dealing with non-int index altogether, although I'm wondering If messages.enumerated().reversed.first { ... }.offset might have been an alternative solution, removing the manual subscripting.